# How outdated is the Nikon D80?

Tags: nikon, dslr

I have a Nikon D80, I know it is no longer produced, but how "outdated" is it? Also, how long do cameras typically last with average use?

Comment: we've 2 questions here and I don't think they relate to each other. The first one is very broad and not localized, cause you are asking about _how outdated_ but you didn't say a reference, I mean how outdated to what? to entry level cameras? to high end cameras? etc...
The second question is totally a different question, so it's better if you edited your question

Comment: Well, now it's two and a half years more outdated than that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came out in 2006 and was replaced in 2008. In the digital photography world, 2008 was millenniums ago. Could you still use one and be satisfied with it - most certainly. Beyond that all information on how "outdated" it is would really depend on your particular use case and expectations.

If you are interested in camera life, I would look at this existing question:
[What are shutter actuations?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/what-are-shutter-actuations)
The above information, in addition to the [camera shutter life database](http://www.olegkikin.com/shutterlife/) will help determine lifespan of a unit.

Comment: but the shutter average life span is not the only factor that affects the camera average life

Comment: @AkramMellice - And that is why I said "will help determine lifespan". Usually the shutter is the important part, but I didn't get detailed because it doesn't really seem like this user is looking for extreme detail either.

Answer (score 3):

Dated, yes. Newer DSLRs are much better and have improved in terms of performance and newer features like Live-View and video.

However, the D80 is still a good camera. Newer models cant change that and it is still better than 99% of cameras with fixed lenses. If you get it for a good price, its very good.

Answer (score 3):

Only you can really say if your camera has become outdated. I suggest a simple experiment:

> Take your camera down to a camera store with an extra memory card and
>   ask the store keeper to let you try your lens(es) on one of their cameras.
>   Take a number of tests shots with the new camera and try to take those
>   same shots with your camera. Then take the images home on your memory
>   cards and do your comparison.

Look at those images objectively and ask yourself if you can see a difference that is worth the money. The newer cameras will probably have quite a few more pixels - but take a look to see if it makes a significant difference with your level of skill and the lenses you tested with.

I still enjoy shooting my D70 (older than your D80) but I feel the in camera JPEG processing isn't quite as good as some of the newer cameras from Nikon. I typically shoot RAW and post process images that I want to keep, saving off both the RAW and JPEG, I feel that this workflow gives me the flexibility to compensate for what I perceive as weaknesses in the JPEG processing that, for example, doesn't preserve highlights all that well.