# After how many shots is a camera considered old?

Tags: body

Many sell used EOS cameras and the number of shots vary a lot. People I have talked to tend to stay away from cameras that have more than 10.000 shots. Given that on a shoot I make an average of 200 shots that would mean that my camera becomes old after about 50 days of usage, for professionals that translates to about 3 months. Sounds a bit strange. So if we take only the number of shots ibto acount and forget the age,model and priceclass into account when is a eos body considered old? Is there a difference in the priceclass too? Is a 60d with 10000 shots worse than a 7d with the same number of shots in terms of aging?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your numbers are probably a factor of 10 out - see [this answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/3817/11371) from the linked duplicate and note that the shutter life expectancy for modern Canon SLRs is about 100,000 (not 10,000) shots.

Comment: Data point: My Sony A77V shutter precharge unit failed at 233,608 counts (which I was told is the usual failure mode.) The A77 counts 2 counts with dual curtain operation and 1 count with electronic 2nd curtain so actual shots between 116,xxx and 233K - so say 175,000.  - :-). Real world results vary very widely for the same model - there are tables somewhere on web. Some with claimed say 100k may get SOME failures at 30k while others last 250,000k +. Really. So, need to look it up. BUT shutter replacement cost is knowable and can be factored into price. ....

Comment: .... My A77 repair cost was reasonable but in any case was covered by service contract ("extended warranty"). | I take "more photos than many". 'Quality AND Quantity' :-) [good theory].