# Why might my camera show spots in video mode?

Tags: canon, sensor, video, artifacts

I own a Canon Rebel T1i, and when I try to record video, there are two dark spots on the screen. These do not appear when I take photos.

Video (spots in center and right center):

[image: Video]

Photo:

[image: Photo]

1. Does the video mode use a different sensor than the photo modes?
2. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your samples are broken.

Comment: Should be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks like dust on the sensor.

Dust is more visible at small apertures and becomes mostly invisible at wide apertures. So it is just that your photo was taken at a wider aperture compared to the video. You can easily confirm this by taking a shot in Aperture priority mode (A) and setting a small aperture (say F/22). The dust should appear again and you should go have your sensor cleaned.

Comment: @y0mbo - take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/why-use-a-small-aperture-when-trying-to-see-sensor-dust.

Comment: Yep, looks like dust to me too.

Comment: I do not understand how aperture size can possibly affect how dust on the *sensor* appears.  It will affect the appearance of dust on the lens, of course, but on the sensor it's basically shadowing the light.  It makes no difference how the light got there because the dust is directly on the sensor.

Comment: @whuber: look at jrista's answer to the question @ysap linked. The short answer is that dust doesn't get on the sensor proper, but on the front of the filters (and such) a few millimeters in front of the sensor.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks.  That makes good sense.  I did not realize the filters were at such a (relatively large) distance from the sensor.