# Thinking of buying a canon 550D - few questions

Tags: canon, photography-basics

I'm thinking of buying a canon 550D second hand. I have a few quesitons:

1) If I buy lenses for this camera, will they work with ALL other canon DSLRs?

2) What should I look out for when buying second hand (I'm buying it from a second hand store)

3) What is this "magic lantern" program and should I get it?

Thank you

Comment: 1) see [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](http:///questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses); 2) See [What should I look for when buying a second-hand dSLR body?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/what-should-i-look-out-for-when-buying-a-second-hand-dslr-body). 3) See [What are the risks of using Magic Lantern?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/what-are-the-risks-of-using-magic-lantern) and [the ML website](http://www.magiclantern.fm)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! As this is a question and answer site rather than a traditional forum, please ask each question separately. (It's okay to post three right in a row if you have three questions.) But of course, please also search for existing Q&A first.

Answer (score 0):

1: yes, with the caveat that EF-S lenses won't work on full-frame. EF work on all EOS DSLR's.

2: value of having to replace the old battery; problems showing up in pictures. Anything you care about ultimately has an effect in the image, so use that as the judgement criteria.

3: look at its website to see the feature set. If you like any of those features, then yes!