# Is the Canon 650D still a good choice?

Tags: canon, dslr, sensor, photography-basics

I am planning on getting my first DSLR soon. I'm torn between the 1300D and 650D because they are about the same price right now. I love the fact that the 650D has a movable touchscreen and a mic input, but I'm not sure if buying a nearly 7-year-old model over the 2016 1300D is a good idea. So what would be better more features but older sensor or new sensor but fewer features? (I know the 1300D has wifi capabilities. but I value that less than the movable screen. But I have never owned a DSLR so if wifi is crazy useful and I don't realize it please tell me.)

Comment: Canon (not the brand) questions dont have an objective answer. Youre going to have personal tastes that affect your decisions someone else cannot account for or will find less important.

Comment: Don't stress too hard about what to get as your first DSLR body. You'll replace sooner or later it if it is really holding you back. Follow the link Philip Kendall posted above to help you think through the decision.

Comment: I was more looking for some information on whether I will have problems that I can't foresee because I don't have a lot of experience when buying an older model.

Comment: Have a look at this if you're thinking of buying a used camera. https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/what-should-i-look-out-for-when-buying-a-second-hand-dslr-body and keep in mind people were once making great pictures with none of the features we have now.

Answer (score 1):

The Canon Rebel T4i/650D was released in 2012.  Just because a digital camera is X number of years old - does not mean that the images it will produce are any worse then the day that it came out.

The question is really down to what features you consider necessary and what your budget (for the camera body) is - neither of which we can answer for you.

The two specific models that you provided as examples are *very* similar.  The differences in the sensor are not relevant to someone buying a DSLR for the first time - some would argue this all day long, but to me its simply not an issue.  I would expect that you can find a lightly used or at a minimum a well discounted Canon Rebel T4i/650D due to its age - so for that reason it seems like an easy answer to me.  Since I don't know the features that are most important to you beyond an articulating touch screen and mic-input, I'd say figure that out and you have your answer.