# How to test used/second-hand lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should one look for when buying a used lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/what-should-one-look-for-when-buying-a-used-lens)

I am going to buy second hand `AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR II`. The price difference is noticable so I would like to take a chance. But before that I want to know how to test it against apparent demages, maybe scratches, motor/mechanical issues. I would really appreciate if someone could give me couple steps which will show apparent issues.

Comment: The above covers used lenses, and this question really covers both used and new "testing" specifically - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12215/how-can-i-test-a-new-lens-to-make-sure-it-is-operating-correctly